# How can I json-serialize a custom iterable?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, types

I'd like to create a type that behaves as a named tuple except that it has a custom representation, which is also respected when serialized as JSON.

The naive by-the-books approach would be something like this:

```python
from typing import NamedTuple
import json


class MyPair(NamedTuple):
    left: str
    right: str

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.left + ':' + self.right


class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, MyPair):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Now `print(MyPair('a', 'b'))` will output `a:b` as intended, but `print(json.dumps([MyPair('a', 'b')], cls=MyJSONEncoder))` will produce `[["a", "b"]]` because `default()` is only called if an object is not primitively serializable as JSON. Since my own type is a tuple, it will be serialized before I get a chance to intervene.

Is there any nice or not-so-nice way of achieving this without making `MyPair` not a `Tuple` or iterating over the entire document in a preprocessing step that replaces all `MyPair` objects by strings?

**Edit:** To address Joran's answer, I still want to retain the ability to serialize complex trees that just *contain* the occasional `MyPair`s. My minimal example might not have made that clear, sorry.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, I had a look at those methods but they don't seem to be designed to be extended so I'd end up duplicating most of the functionality of `JSONEncoder` :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up reimplementing a JSONEncoder more or less from scratch. Since I don't need any fancy pretty-printing, this is fairly straightforward:

```
class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def __init__(self, *, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, sort_keys=False,
                 indent=None, separators=None, default=None):
        super().__init__(skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii, check_circular=check_circular,
                         allow_nan=allow_nan, sort_keys=sort_keys, indent=indent, separators=separators,
                         default=default)
        self._serializers: Set[Tuple[Type, Callable]] = {
            (MyPair, lambda pair: '"' + str(pair) + '"',)
        }

    def default(self, o):
        return super().default(o)

    def encode(self, o):
        return ''.join(self.iterencode(o))

    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
        for t, serializer in self._serializers:
            if isinstance(o, t):
                yield serializer(o)
                break
        else:
            if isinstance(o, bool):
                yield "true" if o else "false"
            elif isinstance(o, str):
                yield '"' + o + '"'
            elif isinstance(o, bytes):
                yield '"' + o.decode("utf-8") + '"'
            elif isinstance(o, int) or isinstance(o, float) or isinstance(o, Decimal):
                yield str(o)
            elif isinstance(o, Dict):
                yield '{'
                for num, (key, value) in enumerate(o.items()):
                    yield bool(num) * ', ' + '"' + str(key) + '": '
                    yield from self.iterencode(value)
                yield '}'
            elif isinstance(o, Sequence):
                yield '['
                for num, value in enumerate(o):
                    yield bool(num) * ', '
                    yield from self.iterencode(value)
                yield ']'
            else:
                yield self.default(o)
```

For custom types, adding the type name and the function that stringifies it to `self._serializers` and you should be good. The `iterencode()` behaves differently from the normal one (mainly in that it yields the brackets separately and not alongside the first or last element) but I couldn't see where this would break anything.

Answer (score 2):

just include the default parameter

```
def my_class_encoder(o):
    if isinstance(o,MyClass):
       return repr(o)

json.dumps(myClassInstance,default=my_class_encoder)
```

its easier to deal with than a real encoder

....

but really just add a def to your class

```
class MyPair(NamedTuple):
    left: str
    right: str
    def serialize(self):
        return list(self)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.left + ':' + self.right
```

and then just

```
 json.dumps(myClassInstance.serialize())
```

this has the benefit of being more clear in what its doing (at least imho)

Comment: Okay, my minimal example was probably to minimal. I of course still want to encode a proper JSON document that just includes MyPair objects somewhere in its tree.